# C Function Prototype With Struct Argument

Tags: c

I want to write a function prototype for a function, whose argument is a pointer to a struct.

```
int mult(struct Numbers *n)
```

However, the struct Numbers, which is defined as

```
struct Numbers {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

is not defined yet. How should I write a suitable prototype for mult?

Comment: You will need a forward declaration.

Comment: forward declarations only work with pointers, so if you ever want to actually pass in a struct by value, you'll need to actually fully define the struct before you use it.  This is because the system knows how big a pointer is, but doesn't know how big an undefined structure is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just declare `struct Numbers` as an incomplete type before your function declaration:

```
struct Numbers;

int mult(struct Numbers *n);
```

Answer (score 4):

You must forward the declaration of the structure to tell the compiler that a struct with that name will be defined:

```
struct Numbers;

int mult(struct Numbers *n) {

}

struct Numbers {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

Mind that the compiler is not able to determine the size in memory of the structure so you can't pass it by value.

Comment: can you ever pass a struct by value in C?

Comment: @Dave absolutely.  It's not normally a good idea, and you have to have the structure fully defined before you use it as a parameter, but there's nothing stopping you if you really want to.

Comment: Huh, I never knew that. I thought passing by value was C++, not C. But yeah I agree that 99% of the time it would be a really bad idea.

Comment: The thing to remember about C (and C++) is that you can do what you want, even if it's a bad idea - you just have to tell the compiler you *really* want to do it. Passing small, frequently created and destroyed, structs by value can reduce dynamic memory allocations, improving performance and reducing heap fragmentation.

Comment: @andy256 in that case you'd still be better off passing a pointer to a local struct. I think it would only be an advantage if the copy costs less than the dereference, which probably means the object is very very small. Maybe a complex number would be a use-case.

Comment: @Dave: passing by value is all you have, in C. You can pass a pointer to an object to enable a function to change it, but this is still just passing the pointer by value, even though you'll sometimes hear people calling this "passing by reference".

Comment: @PaulGriffiths yes OK. Maybe I should clarify that I previously thought only built-in types could be passed, like `int`, `char`, pointer, function pointer.

Comment: @Dave: You can even have a function whose return type is a struct (which leads to some strange edge cases when the struct has an array type member).  Note that when you pass a large struct to a function, it's usually implemented by passing a pointer to a local temporary in the calling function anyway.

Comment: @Dave Yes, or maybe a struct of bit fields.